# Rebinding "Office" key combination to act as Ctrl-R or another modifier

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, remapping, microsoft-keyboard

I have a [Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/microsoft-ergonomic-keyboard/93841NGDWR1H?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) which I am generally enjoying. Unfortunately, it comes with a premade Office key for use in Windows in place of a right Ctrl or Super. I used `xev` to record what the Office key actually outputs, and it acts as a combination of the Ctrl,Shift,Meta,Super keys.

**"Office" key output**

```
Keycode | Name      | Keysym
     37 | Control_L | 0xffe3 |
     50 | Shift_L   | 0xffe1 |
     64 | Meta_L    | 0xffe7 |
    133 | Super_L   | 0xffeb |
```

I have looked at `xmodmap`, but it is deprecated in favor of `setxkbmap`.

Can anybody help me determine how to rebind the key combo above to act as a different modifier, like Ctrl-R or Super-R?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any solution? I just bought this keyboard and keep pressing „Office” key instead of Win (which I heavily use in shortcuts…)

(my Q on SE, with photo and events report: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618786/using-new-2019-microsoft-ergonomic-keyboard-how-to-map-emoji-and-office-keys )